# Azure Datafactory V2 - IfCondition activity cannot include another IfCondition activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using  Azure Data factory V2 and I need to implement two levels of checks with in a parent check validation. example: IF Condition one is true Then I need to check for Condition 2. And, If Condition2 is True then Check for Condition 3.

It's kind of hierarchical checks. When I implement using multiple IF Condition activities within parent IF condition activity, then it doesn't work. I do see following error, when i implement it.

```
"ERROR: IfCondition activity cannot include another IfCondition activity"
```

Answer (score 3):

ADF- V2 doesn't support multiple IfCondition activities with in a single pipeline.

So as a workaround, we used multiple filter activities upfront and split the pipeline flow before IfCondition Activity is invoked.

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example on how you do that with the filter workaround please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the dynamic functions to implement a more complex logic with and() and or().

You can put several continuous if's that set up variables, and use those variables to determine the outcome at the end.

And if that doesn't work for you, or you don't feel like it, you can always Execute a Pipeline inside of the If that uses another If Activity. But I wouldn't recommend this if you want to keep your monitor as easy to read as possible since it launches another pipeline (or more than one)